# Android BroadCastReceiver Not Getting Called for Bluetooth Chat

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to get the devices meta-data after bluetooth discovery is completed, to commence text data transfer. I have used a broadcast receiver to get the discovered devices.

Here's my activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Button btnListen, btnSearch, btnStop;
private TextInputLayout til_incoming, til_outgoing;
private TextInputEditText incomingTET, outgoingTET;
private ListView devicesListView;

private BluetoothAdapter mBTAdapter;
private BluetoothSocket mSocket;

private ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> adapter;
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mBTDeviceList = new ArrayList<>();

private UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("c18fdef0-9c59-11e2-9e96-0800200c9a66");

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_DISCOVERY = 2;

private static final int DISCOVERY_TIME_OUT = 3 * 1000 * 60;
private IntentFilter filter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mBTDeviceList);
    devicesListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    setEnableUI(false);
    mBTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBTAdapter == null) {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Your Device Has no Bluetooth Adapter", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    } else {
        if (!mBTAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }

    if (mBTAdapter.isEnabled()){
        setUpListeners();
        setEnableUI(true);
    }

    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);

}

private void setUpListeners() {
    btnListen.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(this);

    devicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

        }
    });

}

private void setEnableUI(boolean b) {
    btnListen.setEnabled(b);
    btnSearch.setEnabled(b);
    btnStop.setEnabled(b);
    devicesListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private void init() {
    btnListen = findViewById(R.id.btnListen);
    btnSearch = findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    btnStop = findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    incomingTET = findViewById(R.id.incomingTET);
    outgoingTET = findViewById(R.id.outgoingTET);
    til_incoming = findViewById(R.id.til_incoming);
    til_outgoing = findViewById(R.id.til_outgoing);
    devicesListView = findViewById(R.id.devicesListView);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnListen:
            Log.d(TAG, "Listening for Devices");
            Intent discoverIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            discoverIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, DISCOVERY_TIME_OUT);
            startActivityForResult(discoverIntent, REQUEST_DISCOVERY);
            break;
        case R.id.btnSearch:
            Log.d(TAG, "Searching for Devices");
            discoverBluetoothDevices();
            registerBluetoothReceiver();
            break;
        case R.id.btnStop:
            if (mBTAdapter.isEnabled()){
                mBTAdapter.disable();
                Log.d(TAG, "Stopped Listening for Devices");
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Bluetooth Switched Off", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }

}

private void discoverBluetoothDevices() {
    boolean discoveredStatus = mBTAdapter.startDiscovery();
    if (discoveredStatus == false){
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Bluetooth Discovery Failed...\t Try Again", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Discovering Nearby Devices", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnReceive BR");
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(intent.getAction())){
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            mBTDeviceList.add(device);
            Log.d(TAG, "Device Name:\t" + device.getName());
            Log.d(TAG, "Device Addr:\t" + device.getAddress());
            Log.d(TAG, "Device Bond State:\t" + device.getBondState());
            Log.d(TAG, "List Size:\t" + mBTDeviceList.size());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode){
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                setEnableUI(true);
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_DISCOVERY:
            if (resultCode == REQUEST_DISCOVERY){
                Log.d(TAG, "Visible for:\t" + DISCOVERY_TIME_OUT + "\tseconds");
                try {
                    BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket = mBTAdapter
                            .listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord("ETEC304 lab8", uuid);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void registerBluetoothReceiver() {
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerBluetoothReceiver();
}

private void unRegisterBluetoothReceiver() {
    this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    unRegisterBluetoothReceiver();
}

}
```

Other parts of my solution so far, work except the broadcast receiver which never fires. I would like to know if there's a fix for this and how to avoid this occurrence in future.

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Did you set the permission to use Bluetooth in your AndroidMenifest.xml file?

Comment: Yes, the rest of the code works except the receiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this permission in your `AndroidMenifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

And you should call `registerBluetoothReceiver()` first and then call `discoverBluetoothDevices()`;

```
   case R.id.btnSearch:
        Log.d(TAG, "Searching for Devices");
        registerBluetoothReceiver();
        discoverBluetoothDevices();
```

Comment: Receiver not getting called

Comment: Can you post content of 'AndroidMenifest.xml' file.

Comment: I have added it. Kindly check

Comment: Try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`

Comment: Can you post your response as answer so I ca accept it?

Comment: I have posted it.

Comment: Thanks. Oversight on my part

Comment: Never mind, I forgot to write Permissions code. Thanks again.